# Write surrogate unicode to file in Python 3

Tags: python, go, unicode

I want to generate all Unicode code points in Python and write them to a file to be read by some other program (Go). I have something like this:

```py
# store code points by category
categories = collections.defaultdict(list)
for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)):
    categories[unicodedata.category(c)].append(c)

# write unicodes to file
for cc, cp in enumerate(categories):
    with open(cc+'.utf8', "wb") as f:
        list(map(lambda c: f.write(c.encode('utf_8','strict')), cp))
```

I generate all the code points by category and the store them encoded in utf8. So this works with all code points except surrogates (category Cs). I get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Digging [around](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers), I found that I can bypass the error with `surrogatepass`, but it looks like my Go program on the other end picked up invalid code points `U+FFFD` (I'm using `"unicode/utf8"`).

I'm not sure if this is an issue on Python's end or Go's end or that surrogates just can't be stored in a file. How can I store surrogates in a file?

Comment: Wikipedia says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) that a pair of surrogates denotes one character; isolated surrogate code points have no general interpretation.

Comment: Perhaps you can flesh out this question with a little debugging? For example, it seems like you could see what bytes python generates when encoding "\ud800" as utf-8 (with surrogatepass), and then generate a minimal go program that decodes that string, and include the error message. But the answer is probably that surrogates can't appear in valid utf-8, and go `unicode/utf8` doesn't parse invalid utf-8. You can either use a different encoding, or roll your own invalid utf-8 parser.

Comment: As VPfB pointed out: You simply cannot have a single surrogate code point. By itself they do not have any meaning like 0xb2 has no meaning as a code point. Of course you can write any surrogate code point to a file encoded as UTF-8. This will produce several bytes, but these bytes do not have any meaning if interpreted as Unicode. You can store surrogates in file but a single surrogate is not valid like you can store 0xb2 in a file but is is not valid.